# Is the phrase "in a way that" appropriate for a Formal sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, formal-language

> "At first, internet allows the people to connect with others, who live in far-away, in a way that just wasn't possible decades ago."

Is "in a way that" is formal or informal?

Answer (score 1):

"In a way that ..." is standard English, and so acceptable in formal writing.  You might remove the word "just" which is redundant here. Written English tends to use fewer redundant words than spoken.